# Initialising React Context with null values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have often seen a React Context initialised with null values for state and empty functions for state setters. For example:

```
const MyContext = React.createContext({
   myState: null,
   setMyState: () => {}
})
```

The state is then also set inside the Provider component:

```
const MyContextProvider = ({ children}) => {

   const [myState, setMyState] = React.useState(false)

   const providerValues = {
      myState,
      setMyState,
   }

   return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={providerValues}>
         {children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
   )

}
```

What are the advantages to this pattern?

Comment: This is just initial value for the context.

Comment: But they are being explicitly set inside the MyContextProvider component?